# How to secure firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a webservice that uses firebase to get and update data. I am trying to secure access to my firebase db. I already have the downloaded json file in my code, however, I would like to know how to setup the rules within firebase to ensure that only the webservices can access the db.

My current rules are set at

```
".read": true,
".write": true
```

Comment: How is your database accessed from the webservice? Do you use a server and Firebase Admin SDK?

Comment: correct using the Firebase Admin SDK

Comment: did you manage to do it?

Comment: @GiorgosS. not yet ran into some issues these past few weeks will start back on this in a couple hours

Answer (score 0):

As the Firebase Admin SDK is initialized using a service account the service has as much access as the service account used to authenticate it. 
In most cases it has access to read and write all data regardless of Security Rules.

In order to limit the service privileges:
On your server when you initialize the Firebase app, use the `databaseAuthVariableOverride` option by adding this to your service :

```
databaseAuthVariableOverride: 
  {
    uid: "service-name"
  }
```

and structure your rules likes this:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "folder_name": {
      ".read": "auth.uid === 'service-name'",
      ".write": "auth.uid === 'service-name'"
    }
  }
}
```

This way you let only the specified service have access to your database resource and you can define read or write privileges as well.

For additional information and more details check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start)